# Joomla fatal errors are not showing in the error log

Tags: fatal-error, error

I have a very weird and quite frankly highly annoying issue with my website. In my error logs the fatal errors are not showing up. Which means that any deprecated errors gets logged nicely, but actual error 500 fatal errors are not getting logged in that error file. I checked all my plugins, and error reporting is set to maximum, but it still just refuses to log the fatal errors.

When i make a individual PHP file on the server and deliberately code something wrong, the fatal error gets logged nicely. But inside the Joomla environment it just flat out refuses to log the fatal error.

Does anyone heard of this issue before?